# How to define a width in the table row in a table layout equals to the header

Tags: android, layout, android-tablelayout

In my app I have a fragment uses tablelayout. I define the header of my table in the XML and I add the table rows when I instantiate the fragment. Using data from my database.

When I add a table row the width is not equal of the first table row ( the header ).

How can I define the same width for all rows? I have to define a constant width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I created a separate xml that represents the lines in my layout. So, in my TableLayout I add a line using include tag for the header. And the rest of the lines I create during runtime.

Useful link: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: can i know how u did this...any sample code for understanding better?